# webpart.zone = null, why?

Tags: web-part, splimitedwebpartmanager

I have this code:

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
   foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in mgr.WebParts)
   {
       if (wp.Zone != null)){

       // ........
   }

   //.......
}
```

I have the `wp.Zone = null`, why is that, although in debugging I can see the name for the webpart and everything except for the `Zone = null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... 
You can also get Zone ID of the web part this way:

var zoneId = mgr.GetZoneID(wp);

What do you intend to do with Zone object by the way?

Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this could be that webparts are closed the page

Sanjay

Comment: Hi Sanjay, thanks for your answer, no I just places the webpart on the page, in the header zone.. that's it. it's not closed webpart.